# Left join to JSON array

Tags: mysql

in the good times, it was easy to do a join to user - user_comments:

```
SELECT * FROM user LEFT JOIN user_comments WHERE user.id = user_comments.USER_ID

users:
1, 'name1'
2, 'name1'

users_comments
user_id, comment
1      , 'fdfddf'
1      , 'bvvccv'
2      , 'zxczxczxc'
```

but here comes a JSON array. Users:

```
1, 'username'
2, 'username2'
```

and comments:

```
'comment', [1]
'comment2', [1,2]
```

the 2nd column is a JSON array. So, no more records but an array entry in the 2nd column. (ok, I know its not 100% clear, but in this imaginative example lets imagine that a comments may belong to two users).

How to do a left join, and preferably count the number of users?

Comment: What do you mean "here comes a JSON array"?  Where does it come from?  Is it a string stored in MySQL?  Is it a literal provided by your application?  What data actually is in MySQL and how is it structured?  This question is clear as mud.

Comment: agree with the above. this is very unclear. Are you asking if you can do SQL queries on a JSON array? If so, the answer is no.

Comment: in the comments table, the 2nd column is a JSON type.

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: If you want to do this in SQL, it's impossible. If you only have JSON arrays somewhere in your code and you want to do something like "LEFT JOIN" you need to write your own logic.

Comment: so, I need to query all users_comments, do an in_array(userId, $row['json'] ?

Comment: yes, you need to do it manually in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Did you want this? Hope I did not mistake your question;)

```
select c.comment, count(u.id) as userCount
from user_comments c
left join user u on find_in_set(u.id, replace(replace(c.USER_ID, '[', ''), ']', ''))
group by c.comment
```

Comment: The OP [says](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37675538/left-join-to-json-array#comment62828599_37675538) that the column is a "JSON type", which implies MySQL ≥ v5.7.8—in which case [`JSON_CONTAINS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) is available, and would be better than all this string manipulation.